# java: Find multiple modes

Tags: java, mode

This is my code for calculating the mode

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mode1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        int temp_counter, counter, num_occured=0, n, i=0, k=0;

        counter = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter number of data");
        n=input.nextInt();

        int a[]=new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter the data");

        for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            a[i]=input.nextInt();

            temp_counter = 0;
            for(k=0; k<a.length; k++)
            {
                if(a[i] == a[k])
                {
                    temp_counter++;
                    if(counter<temp_counter)
                    {
                        counter = temp_counter;
                        num_occured = a[i];

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(num_occured);

    }
}
```

calculating the mode is to find the most frequent number(s)
if the user entered `2 2 3 4 5` it should display 2 as the mode
and if the user entered `2 2 3 4 4 5` it should display 2 and 4 as the modes

my code displays only the first most frequent number.

How can I make the program display more than one mode if there is more than one most frequent number?

Comment: If this is homework please tag it as such.

Comment: I don't see a question in this post.

Answer (score 4):

Easy method:

Use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`. When you find a new number from the user, Add the input as the key and 1 as the value. When you find a number from the user that's already contained in the HashMap, change the value for that key (the user's number) to the current value + 1.

Once you're done inputting, go through the elements of the HashMap to find the largest value.
You can either make a List to keep track of the keys with largest value, or just go through the hashmap twice.

Code that you may want to clean up later:

```
System.out.println("Enter number of data");
n=input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the data");

HashMap<Integer, Integer> numberMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
int numToAdd = 0;
int highestFreq = 0;
// Count all the numbers
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    numToAdd = input.nextInt();
    if (numberMap.containsKey(numToAdd))
        numberMap.put(numToAdd, numberMap.get(numToAdd) + 1);
    else
        numberMap.put(numToAdd, 1);
    // Check if highest frequency
    if (numberMap.get(numToAdd) > highestFreq)
        highestFreq = numberMap.get(numToAdd);
}

for (Integer num: numberMap.keySet())
{
    if (numberMap.get(num) == highestFreq)
        System.out.print(num + " ");
}
```

Comment: Thanx user1071777 , can u edit the code pls .. I don't how to use this method

Comment: @AishaS, you're going to need to think critically. user1071777 has suggested a good (and pretty common) methodology of approaching this type of problem. We can't do your homework for you, but we can suggest approaches to the problem. You can't expect us to write your code for you to copy-and-paste into homework...

Answer (score 1):

If the mode is the most frequently occurring value you need to keep track of the count of each of these values as you go past them.  An acceptable data structure for this is the Map, which is a key/value pair.  So the key in this instance is the number and the value is the number of times this key has been seen.  When you iterate over the values you need to check the map for existence and increment the count.